# Counting files and directories at each directory level from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have successfully used a batch file which counts the total number of files and directories in a root directory.

Directory structure:

[image: directory structure]

Here is the current script: *(gets the number of files and folders returning subfolders up to the nth child)*.

```bat
@echo off
set "drive=D:\Download\app"
for /d %%r in ("%drive%\*") do (
    echo Path: %%~fr
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('dir/a/s %%~fr ^| find /i "bytes"') do if "%%j"=="File(s)" (
        set numfiles=%%i
    )ELSE (
        for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad %%~fr ^|find /c /v "" ') do set numfolders=%%a)
    echo Files: %numfiles%
    echo Folds: %numfolders%
)
```

First the program outputs the **total number of files** and **total number of folders** in the root directory and then it goes to first subfolder and outputs the same for it's whole tree, then it moves to the next folder at that level etc.

**EDIT**

I have done the part where it go to 1 level of subfolders and get the total number of files and folders but I want it up to N number of subfolders which mean it should output total number for each and every folder in root directory.

Here is the extended code.

```bat
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set "drive=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\Sandukchi"
set numfiles=
set numfolders=
set count=0;
for /d %%r in ("%drive%\*") do (
    echo %%r
    SET /A count=count + 1
    for /d %%a in ("%%r\*") do set modifiedDate=%%~ta
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('dir/a/s "%%r\*" ^| find /i "File(s)"') do set fileSizeBytes=%%k
    for %%* in ("%%r") do set folderName=%%~nx*
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('dir/a/s "%%r\*" ^| find /i "bytes"') do if "%%j"=="File(s)" (
        set numfiles=%%i
    )ELSE (
        for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad "%%r\*" ^|find /c /v "" ') do set numfolders=%%a)
    echo Last Modified Date: !modifiedDate!
    echo Folder Size: !fileSizeBytes! KB
    echo Total Number of Files: !numfiles!
    echo Total Number of Folders: !numfolders!
    (
        echo !count!    %%r     !folderName!        !modifiedDate!  Total Size  !fileSizeBytes!KB   Total Files !numfiles!  Total Folder  !numfolders! 
        echo.
    )>>output.txt
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "tempfile=%temp%\##__##.txt"
SET "dirname="
(
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims= " %%w IN (
 'dir /s "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 IF "%%w"=="Directory" (
  SET "dirname=%sp256%%%y"&SET /a fcnt=0&SET /a dcnt=-2
 ) ELSE (
  FOR /f "delims= " %%p IN ("%%y") DO (
   IF "%%p"=="<DIR>" SET /a dcnt+=1
  )
 )
 IF "%%x"=="File(s)" CALL ECHO %%dirname%%*%%w*%%dcnt%%
)
)>"%tempfile%"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=*" %%a IN ('sort "%tempfile%"') DO ECHO directory %%a&ECHO     files %%b&echo   subdirs %%c

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Generates a tempfile. No attempt made to delete the tempfile as it may contain useful data.

Run a standard `dir/s` command, and pick out the lines which start `directory` (which indicates a new directoryname) and those where the third space-delimited token is `<DIR>` for counting subdirectories. When the lines with second token `File(s)` appears, output the name, filecount and directorycount to a tempfile.

Sort the tempfile and report.

Note: `%%y` contains the third token onwards from each line. This is retokenised, selecting the first token only (default) to `%%p` isolating the third token of the original line.

The tempfile is produced using `*` as a separator since `*` is not a valid filename character.

`dcnt` is set to `-2` to start the count-of-directories because both `.` and `..` are reported as directorynames in a `dir /s`.

Comment: It's working perfectly but its not showing total number of sub directories. it keeps on showing -2.

Comment: This means that `dcnt` isn't being incremented. It could be that `%%p` is never being set to `<DIR>` or there's a transcription error (best to cut-and-paste). If you `echo %%p >con:` within the `do`  block for `for...%%p...` then you should see what is being set in `%%p`. Displaying `%%y` similarly may assist.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try for this code :

```bat
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@For /D  %%D in (*) DO (
    Set "Folder=%%~D"
    PUSHD "!Folder!"
        FOR /F %%H in ('dir /a-d /b 2^>NUL^|find /C /V "" ') DO ( Set "numFiles=%%H" )
        FOR /F %%I in ('dir /ad  /b 2^>NUL^|find /C /V "" ') DO ( Set "numSubFolders=%%I" )
    POPD
    echo The Folder "!Folder!" has !numSubFolders! SubFolders and !numFiles! Files      
    )
)
pause & exit
```